# How to access textbox control located in DataTemplate tags of <phone:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate> from code - behind (MainPage.xaml.cs)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

i have a textbox located in MainPage.xaml :

```
<phone:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>                       
                    <TextBox x:Name="src_textbox" Width="400" TextChanged="src_textbox_TextChanged"/>
                </DataTemplate>
 </phone:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate>
```

now in MainPage.xaml.cs , i want to access `src_textbox` in the event handler `src_textbox_TextChanged`:

the event hanndler is as follows:

```
 void src_textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        string hello = src_textbox.Text();

    }
```

i get red lines under `src_textbox` and error says "it is out of current context" .

How do i access it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I faced the same problem.
**Solution:**

```
void src_textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox temp_textBox = sender as TextBox;

    string hello = temp_textBox.Text();

}
```

You don't need to add name attribute to your `TextBox` control in the xaml.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: @user3442701, your explanation, as always, is on MSDN: [TextBoxBase.TextChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, if this answer has helped you to solve your problem, then please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as is customary on this website.

Comment: @user3442701 please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457091.aspx) for the explanation and if you still don't understand feel free to ask.

Comment: Q1 . why do we have to convert type of sender to THE type Textbox ?            Q2. Is TextBox a .NET Compact Framework control that is why i am not able to access it using name property since .NET Compact Framework control does not support it ?                                         Q3. And if TextBox is a .NET Compact Framework control then how come i am able to access all textboxes placed in layout root grid of MainPage.xaml from 'src_textbox_TextChanged' event handler placed in      MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Every control placed inside a 'DataTemplate' is generated at runtime and that is why you cannot access it with it's name attribute. to know more please refer to this ["HOW TO: Determine the Sender of an Event Without Using the Control.Name Property"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457091.aspx).

Comment: and if i want to access `src_textbox` control in a click event handler of another Button control . is it possible , if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void src_textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtpanorma = (TextBox)sender;
            Debug.WriteLine(txtpanorma.Text);
        }
```

TextBox.Text is a `Property` not a `method` so you cant use `()` for that.